# Java thread dump prio value doesn't correspond with real thread priority on linux?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, pthreads, jstack

I intend to use thread priorities within my Java code.
The application shall run on my Linux system:

```
>uname -a
Linux <host> 3.0.0-15-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP <date> x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

>java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

After some reading in the Web I start my test-application with the following command now:

```
sudo java -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 -jar ThreadPriorityTest.jar
```

The test-application consists of the following two classes:

```java
package ch.mypackage;

public class CountingRunnable implements Runnable {

    private long count = 0;
    private boolean goOn = true;

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void stop() {
        goOn=false;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(long iteration=0;goOn&&iteration<Long.MAX_VALUE;++iteration) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
}


package ch.mypackage;

public class PriorizedCountingThreads {

    private static final int NUM_MILLIS_TO_COUNT_FOR = 1*60*1000;
    private static CountingRunnable[] runnables;
    private static Thread[] threads;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println("MIN_PRIORITY: "+Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println("MAX_PRIORITY: "+Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        int numPriorityLevels = (Thread.MAX_PRIORITY-Thread.MIN_PRIORITY) + 1;
        init(numPriorityLevels);
        startThreads();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(NUM_MILLIS_TO_COUNT_FOR);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopRunnables();
        printCounts();
    }

    private static void printCounts() {
        for (int i = 0; i < runnables.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(threads[i].getName() + " has priority: " + threads[i].getPriority() + " and count:" + runnables[i].getCount());
        }
    }

    private static void stopRunnables() {
        for (int i = 0; i < runnables.length; ++i) {
            runnables[i].stop();
        }
    }

    private static void startThreads() {
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }

    private static void init(int numPriorityLevels) {
        runnables = new CountingRunnable[numPriorityLevels];
        threads = new Thread[runnables.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < runnables.length; ++i) {
            int priority = i + 1;
            runnables[i] = new CountingRunnable();
            threads[i] = new Thread(runnables[i]);
            threads[i].setPriority(priority);
            threads[i].setName("PriorityThread_" + priority);
        }
    }
}
```

If I let the program count for one minute (NUM_MILLIS_TO_COUNT_FOR=1*60*1000) then I get the following output:

```
MIN_PRIORITY: 1
MAX_PRIORITY: 10
PriorityThread_1 has priority: 1 and count:12658044343
PriorityThread_2 has priority: 2 and count:19008431582
PriorityThread_3 has priority: 3 and count:30618946099
PriorityThread_4 has priority: 4 and count:34408365142
PriorityThread_5 has priority: 5 and count:36694025023
PriorityThread_6 has priority: 6 and count:40493710165
PriorityThread_7 has priority: 7 and count:42826305342
PriorityThread_8 has priority: 8 and count:42203891414
PriorityThread_9 has priority: 9 and count:43128747383
PriorityThread_10 has priority: 10 and count:43416371500
```

According to this output the priorities seem to have the expected impact!
But if I generate a thread dump with "jstack" or "kill -s QUIT", then I get the following output, which implies that EVERY THREAD HAS THE SAME PRIORITY(prio=10):

```
    "PriorityThread_10" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e406f800 nid=0x12e6 runnable [0x00007ff7e2562000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_9" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e406d800 nid=0x12e5 runnable [0x00007ff7e2663000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_8" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e406b000 nid=0x12e4 runnable [0x00007ff7e2764000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_7" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e4069000 nid=0x12e3 runnable [0x00007ff7e2865000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_6" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e4067000 nid=0x12e2 runnable [0x00007ff7e2966000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_5" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e4065000 nid=0x12e1 runnable [0x00007ff7e2a67000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_4" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e4063000 nid=0x12e0 runnable [0x00007ff7e2b68000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_3" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e4061000 nid=0x12df runnable [0x00007ff7e2c69000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_2" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e405d000 nid=0x12de runnable [0x00007ff7e2d6a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

"PriorityThread_1" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff7e4049800 nid=0x12dd runnable [0x00007ff7e2e6b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ch.mypackage.CountingRunnable.run(CountingRunnable.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

If I do the same on a Windows machine, the prio values are the correct ones, according to the priority mappings I found [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml).

So, is this a bug in jstack, or am I doing something wrong?

If I execute "top | grep java" I get the following:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3394 root      20   0 4444m  15m 8376 S  789  0.1   0:47.52 java
```

which implies that the main Thread has a priority of 20, while "top -H | grep java" results in the following output:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND     

 3457 root      15  -5 4444m  15m 8384 R   99  0.1   0:08.60 java
 3456 root      16  -4 4444m  15m 8384 R   97  0.1   0:08.41 java
 3455 root      17  -3 4444m  15m 8384 R   93  0.1   0:08.42 java
 3454 root      18  -2 4444m  15m 8384 R   97  0.1   0:08.27 java
 3453 root      19  -1 4444m  15m 8384 R   97  0.1   0:07.50 java
 3452 root      20   0 4444m  15m 8384 R   51  0.1   0:07.44 java
 3451 root      21   1 4444m  15m 8384 R   35  0.1   0:04.83 java
 3450 root      22   2 4444m  15m 8384 R   99  0.1   0:04.78 java
 3449 root      23   3 4444m  15m 8384 R   95  0.1   0:07.47 java
 3448 root      24   4 4444m  15m 8384 R   18  0.1   0:02.85 java
```

which shows that the java thread priorities really affect the priorities of the OS-threads.

But where does jstack have a value of 10 in prio=10 from?
Is it just an arbitrary value?

Comment: Note that Java threads do not necessarily correspond to system processes/threads (it might be a single process JVM that does the scheduling internally, for example) and thus Java's thread priority does not necessarily match the OS thread priority.

Comment: *Regardless* of whether or not Java threads do correspond to OS threads, the Java priority levels are nowhere specified to be numerically equal to the OS levels.

Comment: @Thomas AFAIK, openJDK don't make use of green threads at all, whatever the platform.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128039/java-threads-priority-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Thread priority in Java are a very very sensitive subject...
You can find an intersting post on StackOverlow here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170304/1343096

Basically try to change your priority policy to 42 :

```
-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42
```

Let us know if it does the trick for you!

You can find all the explanations by following the link.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) state

> **NOTE** - This utility is unsupported and may or may not be available in future versions of the JDK.

So I would assume that the output of `jstack` may not be accurate as the implementation details on linux may have changed.

The values reported by `htop -H` are in line with [this article](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml), which you included in your question, and are those upon which the java-processes are sheduled inside the linux kernel.

If you need to map the output of jstack to the threads reported by `top -H` you only need to convert the `nid` from `jstack` to decimal or the `pid` from `top -H` to hex. [See this article](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.de/2012/08/which-java-thread-consumes-my-cpu.html)

Regarding your source code: the programm would not terminte when I run it. Three hints when writing production multi-tasking code:

- If you know everything is done (as after calling `printCounts()` from `main`) don't hesitate to use `System.exit(0);` therby ensuring all threads are terminated.
- If you want to test your code for behaviour during parallel execution it is often good to create all `Thread`s first and get them to work synchronously. Calling `await()` on a shared [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) as first statement of the worker will often do this trick well enough.
- While `boolean` read and write is to be atomic as per [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), I would recommend declaring trigger-variables like your `goOn` field to be volatile as this also influences how the compiler will optimize your code.

Using either `volatile` or `System.exit(0)` your benchmark terminated normally.